# MapReduce Code to find the average temperature of certain city stations

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I take my first steps with hadoop 3.1.2, I have datasets like:

```
id station;     city;       temperature
1;              New York;       14
3;              New York;       20
2;              Bristol;        29
8;              Rome;          -10
30;             Bristol;         2
10;             Rome;            0
1;              New York;       10
8;              Rome;           10
```

through Hadoop, with mapreduce, I should get: the grouping by ID station, and the average of temperatures.
However, I'm not interested in all cities, but only in those with station ID = 1, 8, for example ...

Scenario: counting the total / average temperature of cities
Map (Key, Value) -->  Key: id station with name city, value: their temperatures.
Reduce: group by id station + name city, and take average temperature of each station.

getting something like:

```
City        -   Station;         Average Temperature
New York    -       1;                  7
Rome        -       8;                  0
```

Here is the code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

import java.io.IOException;


public class SingleMapperReducer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "City Temperature Job");
        job.setMapperClass(TemperatureMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(TemperatureReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }


    /*
    Id, City, Temperature
    1; New York; 14
    3; New York; 20
    2; Bristol; 29
    1; Rome; 20
    2; Rome; -10
    2; Bristol; 2
    3; New YOrk; 10
    1; Rome; 10
    */

    private static class TemperatureMapper
            extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String txt = value.toString();
            String[] tokens = txt.split(";");
            String id = tokens[0].trim();
            String temperature = tokens[2].trim();

            if(id.equals("1"))
            {
                id="New York - 1";
            }
            else if(cat.equals("8"))
            {
                id="Rome - 8";
            }            

            if (temperature.compareTo("Temperature") != 0)
                context.write(new Text(id), new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(temperature)));
        }
    }



    private static class TemperatureReducer    //on id city
            extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                           Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            int n = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
                n +=1;
            }
            result.set(sum/n);
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }
}
```

do you think it will work?
the part of the code where I developed the filter on ID station, is it correct ? 
are there any other ways to apply this filter?

thanks to those who want to help me!

update 26/11

@cricket_007 @amey-shirke

thanks ! I tried to execute the code, making the suggested changes:

```
if (id.equals ("1") || id.equals ("8")) {
    id = id + "-" + tokens [1];
    context.write (new Text (id), new IntWritable (Integer.parseInt (temperature)));
}
```

and more these:

```
  Configuration conf = new Configuration ();
  Job job = Job.getInstance (conf, "word count");
  job.setJarByClass(SingleMapperReducer.class);
```

-

the system performs the process but gives me an empty output file.

p.s I tried hadoop's mapreduce framework on a trivial "wordcount" case, it works.

what could have happened?
thx

Comment: Why don't you run it and see what happens? You can always pass a small dataset through and add logs to your code so that you can trace what happens.

Comment: I tried this, but I see an empty file as an output

Answer (score -1):

Few points to note:

1. If you are only concerned with ids 1 & 8, Just context.write() those. Something in lines of

```
if(id.equals("1") || id.equals("8")){
   id=id + " - "+ tokens[1];
   context.write(new Text(id), new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(temperature)));
}
```

2. this piece of code doesnt help and is not required `(temperature.compareTo("Temperature") != 0)`

Comment: Just print out tokens array in logs & see if you get the expected values

Comment: how ? with the line  "context.write(new Text(id), new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(temperature)));" ? because when I execute hadoop command I see an empty file as otuput.